# Explain why $x^+=A^+b$ is the shortest possible solution to $A^TA\hat{x}=A^Tb$

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning, least-squares, pseudoinverse

I'm was going through the chapter on pseudoinverse in *intro to linear algebra* by Strang, and it says

**The vector $x^+=A^+b$ is the shortest possible solution to $A^TA\hat{x}=A^Tb$ Reason: The difference $\hat{x}-x^+$ is in the nullspace of $A^TA$. This is also the nullspace of A, orthogonal to $x^+$.**

I get that it is essentially saying **$x^+$** is the best least squares solution for **$Ax=b$**. But I'm having a difficult time understanding the reason provided by Strang.

Comment: "The vector $A^+=A^+b$" makes no sense as $A^+$ is a matrix (and $x^+=A^+b$ is the vector). I have edited that as a typo, but you change my edit back. What do you mean by $A^+=A^+b$?

Comment: @A.G. we were both editing at the same time and i accidentally overwrote yours.

Comment: Is $\hat x - x^T$ a typo?  I think it must be.

Comment: @littleO yes. I apologize for making so many typos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse $A^+$ satisfies

1. $P=AA^+$ is the orthogonal projector, i.e. $PA=A$ and $P=P^T$, and
2. $Q=A^+A$ is the orthogonal projector, i.e. $QA^+=A^+$ and $Q=Q^T$.

With this in mind it is easy to see that $x^+=A^+b$ is a solution to $A^TA\hat x=A^Tb$ as
$$
A^TAx^+=A^TAA^+b=A^TPb=A^TP^Tb=(PA)^Tb=A^Tb.
$$
Moreover, it is the smallest norm solution. Let $z=\hat x-x^+$ for another solution $\hat x$, then
$$
A^TAz=A^TA(\hat x-x^+)=A^TA\hat x-A^TAx^+=A^Tb-A^Tb=0.
$$
That is, **The difference $\hat x−x^+$ is in the nullspace of $A^TA$**. 
Pre-multiply by $z^T$ to get $z^TA^TAz=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\|Az\|^2=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $Az=0$. That is **This is also the nullspace of $A$.** Now
$$
z^Tx^+=z^TA^+b=z^TQA^+b=z^TQ^TA^+b=(Qz)^TA^+b=(A^+\underbrace{Az}_{=0})^TA^+b=0.
$$
So $x^+\bot z$. That is, **orthogonal to $x^+$.** Therefore
$$
\|\hat x\|^2=\|x^++z\|^2=\|x^+\|^2+2\underbrace{z^Tx^+}_{=0}+\|z\|^2=\|x^+\|^2+\|z\|^2\ge\|x^+\|^2.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I was able to derive the projection matrix $P=AA^+$ by $x^+=A^+b$ ->  $Ax^+=AA^+b$. But I'm not sure how Q was derived. In the book it says $P$ is the projection matrix to the column space of A which makes sense. But $Q$ is the projection matrix onto the row space of A. How do you exactly project it to the row space? Also the way you wrote it, it seems like Q is projecting onto column space of $A^+$

Comment: @MoneyBall Property $QA^+=A^+AA^+=A^+$ is the property 2 in [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Definition). It is also true that $A=AA^+A=AQ$ which after transposing becomes $A^T=QA^T$. It is precisely what you say that $Q$ is a projector onto column space of $A^T$ (=the row space of $A$). It is the same space as the column space of $A^+$.

Answer (score 3):

At this point in the book, Strang has established that $A A^+$ projects onto the range of $A$.

It follows that if $x^+ = A^+ b$ then
$$
A^T A x^+ = A^T A A^+ b = A^T \tilde b
$$
where $\tilde b$ is the projection of $b$ onto the range of $A$.

Now, Strang has claimed that if $A^T A \hat x = A^T b$ then
$\hat x - x^+$ is in the null space of $A^T A$, which is equivalent to claiming that
$$
\underbrace{A^T A x^+}_{A^T \tilde b} = \underbrace{A^T A \hat x}_{A^T b}.
$$
Is it really true that $A^T \tilde b = A^T b$?

To see that this is true, decompose $b$ as
$$
b = \tilde b + \bar b,
$$
where $\bar b$ is the projection of $b$ onto the null space of $A^T$.
(This decomposition uses the fact that the range of $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the null space of $A^T$.)
We see that
$$
A^T b = A^T \tilde b + A^T \bar b = A^T \tilde b.
$$
This proves the claim mentioned above.

To finish off the problem, note that
$x^+$ belongs to the range of $A^T$, and $\hat x - x^+$
belongs to the null space of $A$.  Hence,
$$
x^+ \perp \hat x - x^+.
$$
It now follows from the Pythagorean theorem that
$$
\| \hat x \|^2 = \| x^+ \|^2 + \| \hat x - x^+ \|^2.
$$
This shows that $\| \hat x \| \geq \| x^+ \|$.

Answer (score 2):

There are good answers posted. Here is another perspective.

Start with the matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, the data vector $b\in\mathbb{C}^{m}$ which has a range space component. We are looking for a solution vector $x\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$. We are talking about the linear system $\mathbf{A} x = b$. Specifically, the least squares problem where $\mathbf{A}x -b > 0$. We are discussing the solution to the least squares problem
$$
 x_{LS} = 
\left\{
  x\in\mathbb{C}^{n} \colon
\lVert
  Ax - b
\rVert_{2}^{2}
\text{ is minimized}
\right\}
$$
This set of minimizers is given by
$$
  x_{LS} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}b} + 
\color{red}{\left(
  \mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{A}
\right) y},
\quad y \in \mathbb{C}^{n}
$$
where the coloring distinguishes $\color{blue}{range}$ space and $\color{red}{null}$ space vectors. The least squares minimizers are the affine space represented by the dashed red line.

[image]

The need for least squares arises because the data vector is not confined the range space:
$$
b = \color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}} + \color{red}{b_{\mathcal{N}}}
$$

What are the lengths of the vectors in this set?
$$
\begin{align}
\lVert
  x_{LS} 
\rVert_{2}^{2}
&=
\lVert
\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}b} + 
\color{red}{\left(
  \mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{A}
\right) y}
\rVert_{2}^{2} \\
%
&=
\lVert
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}b}
\rVert_{2}^{2} + 
\lVert
\color{red}{\left(
  \mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{A}
\right) y}
\rVert_{2}^{2}
\end{align}
$$
How to minimize this length? Adjust $y$ so that there is no null space contribution. That is, the least squares minimizers of least length is 
$$
\color{blue}{x_{LS}} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}b}.
$$

Comment: Nice figure. What software did you use to draw it?

Comment: @user1551: Mathematica.